# VM inbound traffic only works with outbound traffic at same time

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, vps, kvm-virtualization

I've recently configured a VM on a low-end rental VPS service to try to improve load times for a web site I'm running. (The web site makes use of high-reliability technologies that require full access to a VM, so I can't just use cheap IIS site hosting.) I've got it all set up, and it's working well (and way faster than my cable modem :-) with one caveat, and it's an odd one.

The VPS doesn't seem capable of receiving inbound traffic unless it has just recently sent an outbound packet. So, if the server is just sitting there, and I'm connected to the "KVM" VNC connection, I can use the system, it's fully responsive, but it doesn't respond to pings or connection attempts on its Internet interface. As soon as I initiate some network traffic from the VPS outbound, such as ping requests, browsing a web page, downloading OS updates or what have you, then suddenly it starts getting & replying to pings. As soon as the outbound traffic drops off, the site drops off the Internet again.

The site is up and running right now only because I have an ongoing "ping" operation in a console window hitting another IP of mine. One outbound ping a second seems to keep the site pretty much accessible.

It seems very odd to me that the inbound traffic should be contingent on outbound traffic in this way. The VPS provider assures me it's nothing they're in charge of -- but then at the rates I'm paying I don't know if I expect them to understand every last detail of the service they're offering. :-)

Has anyone heard of this sort of behaviour before?

Here are all of the configuration details I know that I can think of, off the top of my head:

- Host OS: I *believe* Red Hat, but definitely a variant of Linux. The guest was preinstalled with Red Hat virtio drivers. I don't know any other details.
- Guest OS: Windows Server 2008 R2, fully patched
- Network drivers: Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter, 61.72.104.11000, built 2015-09-22

Comment: In a raw approach it seems a duplicate ip/mac address misconfiguration, so everythings works if you continue to ping outside propagating your L2/L3 informations in this way. 
Could you post your NIC configuration ? Your virtual interface are in bridge with metal interface?

Comment: It sounds like a firewall issue. Many times servers are locked down from inbound traffic to prevent people from scanning open ports, probing ssh logins etc.

Comment: Good thinking @FrancescoP :-) I'm pretty sure that's the case -- they've assigned the same IP to both my VPS and another one in the same data centre. I ran a packet capture, and sure enough, I get random snippets of TCP conversations on port numbers I don't even have open in my VPS, and they're packets plucked right out of the middle, without any of the connection initialization. Classic symptoms of duplicate IPs on the same subnet.

If you want to turn it into an answer I'll happily mark it as such. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a raw approach it seems a duplicate ip/mac address misconfiguration, so everythings works if you continue to ping outside propagating your L2/L3 informations in this way. Could you post your NIC configuration ? Your virtual interface are in bridge with metal interface?

Comment: The duplicate IP was it. (More detailed reply in question comments.) Thanks very much!